# PHPMailer - how to count number of successfully sent messages

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm in the process of migrating my project from Swiftmailer to PHPMailer.  `SwiftMailer::send()` returns the number of messages that were successfully sent (which I realize doesn't necessarily mean *delivered*).  How do I get that same information from PHPMailer?

I know I can restructure my code to send to 1 recipient at a time, but that seems sub-optimal.  I'd like to be able to send a single message to multiple addresses/Bccs, and count the number that were accepted for delivery.

Comment: Call **getAllRecipientAddresses()** to get all, but there's functions available to get (To, Cc and Bcc) as **getCcAddresses()**

Comment: @Triby I don't believe that is a list of all addresses for which delivery was accepted - just a list of all addresses that have been added.  If I've added 5 emails to send to, and only 3 were accepted for delivery, I'm looking for some way to get "3"